# Shorter way to go to specific directory path

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation

Some time ago I saw that there is a possibility to go to a directory like `/home/user/something/` by typing:

```
cd /h/u/s
```

and by hitting the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key.

Can you remind me the name of this app / script / anything?

Comment: Not sure, but that was a feature of another shell instead of the default Bash one. If I remember right, it was either `zsh` or `ksh`... Maybe.

Comment: It is a feature if `zsh`

Comment: bash does have an autocomplete feature where you can press tab to autofill the directory name. so you can type `cd /h` and press tab to immediately get `cd /home`( as long as there is no other directory starting with "h"

Comment: ``cd h*/u*/s*<enter>`` works in bash but is probably not what you are looking for. I prefere the usual ``cd h<tab>/u<tab>/s<tab>`` method. As already mentioned by others what you are looking for is a feature of ``zsh``

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a way to do that in Bash, however perhaps it was Zsh?

[image: s1]

> Hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd>

[image: s2]

> Hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image: s3]

Comment: Any idea how to do it in bash?

Comment: @arczi Have a look at this, but it has some caveats: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25096279/4316166. Other than that you might have to switch shell if you really want that feature. For normal use Zsh is mostly just a superset of Bash (same syntax, little differences in how commands are executed but not noticeable for basic usage), so you probably wouldn't even notice the difference, but really it depends on how you use the shell. You could try giving it a shot if you feel like.